# Attempting to execute SQL statements using text file in command line

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am very new to SQL and in fact just started yesterday. The book I am following is asking me to run sql statements from a text file they provided. However, I am getting an error message and I dont understand why. Here is the commands I entered along with the error message:

```
 mysql> use bank;
Database changed
mysql> source c:\sql\LearningSQLExample.sql;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    9
Current database: bank

--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.12, for Win64 (x86_64)

Connection id:          9
Current database:       bank
Current user:           lrngsql@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.6.12 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 1 day 4 hours 9 min 17 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 6474  Slow queries: 1  Opens: 111  F
tables: 79  Queries per second avg: 0.063
--------------

ERROR:
Unknown command '\L'.
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'c:ql\LearningSQLExample.sql', error: 2
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash. Type `source c:\\sql\\LearningSQLExample.sql;`

Comment: Its seems to have worked, but this is what was displayed: `ERROR: Unknown command '\\'`. And then a load of 'Query OK statements were displayed. Also, why is there a need for the \ escape character?

Comment: \s and \L will be interpreted as special characters. \s does exist while \L does not, hence the error. \\ converts to a single \

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional solution when for newer version of mySQL command line
Rename the `LearningSQLExample.sql` file to something that have underscore in it.
Something like s_s.sql then at the command line try

```
source c:/temp/s_s.sql;
```